# SPARQL support protege 5

Tags: sparql, protege

what's the level of support of SPARQL in protege 5.2.0 SPARQL Query Plugin 2.02?

I tried using

```
FILTER STRSTARTS(STR(?subject), STR(prefix:))
```

and I get

> Unknown function 'http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#starts-with'

I can't seem to find a listing with the supported functions and capabilities.

Thanks

Comment: the SPARQL Query Plugin is still based on a very old Sesame 2.7.12 lib. But according to the source code, it covers full SPARQL 1.1 and also the function in your query

Comment: At least I can see the code in [an old fork](https://github.com/ansell/openrdf-sesame/blob/2.7.x/core/queryparser/sparql/src/main/java/org/openrdf/query/parser/sparql/ast/ASTStrStarts.java)

Comment: did you try with braces around the function, i.e. `FILTER(strstarts ... )` ? shouldn't change anything, but who knows ...

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work. The function can be parsed but the evaluation part wasn't implemented, see [here](https://github.com/ansell/openrdf-sesame/tree/2.7.x/core/queryalgebra/model/src/main/java/org/openrdf/query/algebra) - that's why the mentioned only *"99.9% compliance with the SPARQL 1.1 Query Language W3C Recommendation."* in their [release notes](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sesame/files/Sesame%202/2.7.0/).

Comment: The only solution would be to upgrade to RDF4J in Protege which is the successor of Sesame. There is already an open [ticket](https://github.com/protegeproject/rdf-library/issues/6), but I guess nobody read it or is responsible for it - and I guess it needs a fair amount of time to migrate the new API.

Comment: `filter regex(str(?s), "^http://example\\.com/ontology#")` should work.

Comment: In the Snap SPARQL Plugin, `filter strstarts(str(?s), str(:))` should work (but you have to enable reasoning).

Comment: I vote for "did you try with braces around the function" i.e. `filter(...)`. IMHO trying without the brackets should be a syntax error; and it will be very weird if their lack causes the error reported , but I've seen stranger things happen..

Answer (score 2):

I just struggled with this myself. The SPARQL Query Plugin for Protege 5.5.0 has not been updated since 2012, one year before SPARQL 1.1 was a W3C recommendation. Thus, the only way I found to get SPARQL 1.1 is by using the Snap SPARQL Plugin. I hope this saves someone from all the time I wasted figuring this out.