# year() function DOES NOT work in SPARQL (Protege)

Tags: sparql, protege

This query throws an error

> Unknown function 'http://www.w3.org/xpath-functions#year-from-dateTime'

My code:

```
select ?age where { 
  bind( "1799-12-14"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date> as ?death )
  bind( "1732-02-22"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date> as ?birth )
  bind(year(?death)-year(?death) AS ?age)
}
```

And I've been googling for so many hours without finding any helpful information. Do I have to add a prefix that refers to the function somewhere? Why on earth does protege not have built-in dateTime conversion functions?

```
select ?age where { 
  bind( "1799-12-14"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date> as ?death )
  bind( "1732-02-22"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date> as ?birth )
  bind(int(?death)-int(?death) AS ?age)
}
```

I've tried to cast the date to integer but that throws another error message. Does anyone know how to properly cast dateTime to int with Protege SPARQL?

Comment: See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299218/sparql-support-protege-5) - Protege is based on an older SPARQL API where many functions are not implemented. There is also a [ticket](https://github.com/protegeproject/rdf-library/issues/6) on Github.

Comment: alternatively, you could use Apache Jena or RDF4J from command line for querying a local file